# CefSharp does not register js object for remote users

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, cefsharp

I have a page on a remote server that is displayed on cefsharp WebBrowser, for obvious reasons of compatibility with some components that require FlashPlayer I cannot change the cef version.

I know there are newer versions that still support flashplayer, but i'm having trouble getting flash content to start automatically. Anyway, the code below works just fine for me, but not for users that view the page online.

they get the following error: TypeError: appCommand.sendMessage is not a function

> c#

```
ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("link");
browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("appCommand", this, true);

public void SendMessage(string msg)
{
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

> js

```
document.getElementById('test-button').onclick = function()
{
    appCommand.sendMessage("Hello world!");
}
```

Comment: What version are you using? What exactly is a user who calls the function remotely?

Comment: @amaitland the version is 51.0.0. The user simply clicks on a button that calls this function appCommand.sendMessage("msg");

Comment: I was wondering if these settings could help: settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("allow-universal-access-from-files", "1"); settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add ("disable-web-security", "1");

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't answer my question, what is a remote user? How does that user differ from you? Doubt those command line args will do anything. Is there a reason you are stuck with version 51? It's ancient, the last version to support flash was 80 something from memory. Currently not enough information to speculate what's going on here. Please try adding more detail.

Comment: @amaitland the users differ from me by the fact that they are not connected in my local network.

Comment: Are you developing a new app? Deploying an existing application? Are there other machines where the application works successfully? You gotta give me more to go on. Check the log file for errors https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community You can close or delete this question, I solved by updating CefSharp. thx